# The difference between each package (like react-router-dom & react-router-website) in React-router V4

Tags: react-router-v4

In React-router v4, I know **react-native is use for react-native**, but for website, should I install **react-router-dom** or **react-router-website**? how about **react-router**

[packages in v4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgUXQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You just need **react-router-dom** when you're building your web app. **react-router-website** is literally code for [React Router's website](https://reacttraining.com/react-router). **react-router** is all of the core components that are shared between **react-router-dom** and **react-router-native** but each of those packages individually also exports what's in core, so you don't ever need to install **react-router**.